# Rebind *this in C++ thread object, move constructor, move assignment

Tags: c++, lambda, this, move, stdthread

I have a class with a thread object that is using class members.

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    atomic_int a;
    thread t;

public:
    MyClass()
    : a(0),
      t([this]() // <- grab 'this' pointer
      {
          while(true)
          {
              sleep_for(milliseconds(1000));
              a++; // <- use 'a' field of the object (through 'this')
          }
      })
    {
    }
};
```

Question: How to implement move assignment / constructor, so that the thread object references the new MyClass object?

Naive (bad) implementation:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(MyClass&& other)
    : a(other.a),
      t(other.t) // <- Thread object is moved to the new MyClass object
                 //    but it's still referencing the old 'this' pointer.
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: House `a` and `t` in a separate helper class, have `MyClass` allocate it on the heap and hold it by `unique_ptr`. In effect, `MyClass` becomes a thin wrapper around the (non-movable, non-copyable) class that does actual work.

Comment: This is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This is a very "uncomfortable" mechanism for having a thread attached to an instance of a class. There are better, more solid, designs. Rethink your class design, overall.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: In the answer section please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t move an `atomic` object.  This is a hint: while you could write your own move constructor that initialized the new object’s `a` with the *value* of the old one, the behavior wouldn’t be atomic!  (You would *also* have to synchronize between threads to *publish* the address of the new atomic object.)

So don’t move it.  That immediately implies that the atomic object must not be a (direct) member of your movable class; the next simplest thing (aside from making it local to the lambda, which is presumably undesirable) is to own it via `unique_ptr` (which already has the desired movability-but-not-copyability).  Then the lambda can capture the raw pointer to avoid having a reference to (a subobject of) `this` that could dangle:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    unique_ptr<atomic_int> a;
    thread t;

public:
    MyClass()
    : a(new atomic_int(0)),
      t([a=a.get()]() // <- grab pointer to atomic
      {
          while(true)
          {
              sleep_for(milliseconds(1000));
              ++*a;
          }
      })
    {
    }
};
```

The default move constructor/assignment are then correct.  (Note that assignment calls `terminate` if the thread is still running, which makes sense since you just deallocated the `atomic_int` it was using!)